# How to add COLUMN with JSOB Type?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I can't find example how to add JSONB column to PostgreSQL.

I tried: `ALTER TABLE available_routes ADD COLUMN accounts TYPE JSONB;`
But got error about wrong syntax near "JSONB"

Comment: PostgreSQL Version 9.6

Comment: remove `type` ?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
ALTER TABLE available_routes ADD COLUMN accounts JSONB;
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html

> ADD [ COLUMN ] [ IF NOT EXISTS ] column_name data_type [ COLLATE
>   collation ] [ column_constraint [ ... ] ]

`column_name data_type` - with no `type` between

Comment: When I should use TYPE keyword?

Comment: `ALTER [ COLUMN ] column_name [ SET DATA ] TYPE data_type [ COLLATE collation ] [ USING expression ]` - when changing type of column, not when adding a column. I agree - it could be `ADD [ COLUMN ] [ IF NOT EXISTS ] column_name [TYPE] data_type`, but its not :)